# How to get Contact Id from URL

Tags: apex

I am having a Standard object `Contact` which has a relationship with an Custom Object `Demo__c`.

So, in `Contact Page Layout`, we can create a new `Demo__c` record by clicking the `New` button.

I am overriding the `New` button of `Demo__c` object.

So, I am wondering how to get `Contact ID` from URl, when I will click the `New` Button from the Contact Page layout.

I can see the URL coming `?CF00Nj0000003ZA8g=Mr.+Sanket+Biswal&CF00Nj0000003ZA8g_lkid=003g000000KM0e1&scontrolCaching=1&retURL=%2F003g000000KM0e1&sfdc.override=1`

and `retURL` contains the `Contact ID`, but how to fetch it in the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string conID = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL');
conID = conID.replace('%2F,'');
```

Will get you the value of the return URL and replace the %2F

It would be cleaner if you just update the custom button to pass the conID in the URL parameters and then you can just get that parameter.